# Is there a word for words being lost and rediscovered in different time periods?

Tags: linguistics

In [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325985/is-the-use-of-the-term-bugged-to-refer-to-software-bugs-universal-in-english), it became clear that a verb, 'to bug', seems to have been current in the 1950s and 60s, then dropped out of favour entirely, then re-appeared in the Internet age. However, the new usage probably has nothing to do with the old form.

Is there a recognised idea of a word being 'reinvented' or rediscovered in different time periods? Or is it too infrequent to be a recognised concept?

Comment: The linked thread seems altogether to neglect the sense of the verb *bug* as *bother* or *pester.*

Comment: That's try. And also the sense of 'to install a monitoring device'. It's the words  concerning software bugs -- buggy, debugging, etc